Shared Hosting eg godaddy restrict user DB creation from web app context. Is VPS the only solution
Still learning am fearly new to The Dev world. Am Working on a personal project deploy the app and realize shared web hosting restrict CREATE DB for user from the web application context when dealing with new user and tenant DB creation using the primary db user defined in the web app .env still researching but if someone could probably let me know if my only solution is VPS for a muli databse setup where registered users should have their own database? This is the error:
Failed to create database: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'agsubscription'@'localhost' to database 'agtenant_66fded7190f5d' (Connection: landlord, SQL: CREATE DATABASE agtenant_66fded7190f5d)
I want a DB to be created after user select their subdomain name and submit the form. I call the web hosting am using and wad advised it can only be done manually. So I amd wondering if I have to now create some database manually or from the admin stand point the the user is assigned a database which in my view is manual and not feasible. So my other option is using a VPS but whats an affordable price since this is my personal development for now.

I would never recommend shared hosting for anything, ever. Learn to admin your own box and you'll never look back. Low end full-root VPS plans are dirt cheap nowadays. Alternatively, you might consider a scalable pay-as-you-go containerized system like Heroku or Fly.io. That said, you've posted no information about the app, but if you have to create a new database for each user, then you're likely doing something very wrong.

A multi-tenant application with separate storage is quite an advanced product and basic hosting accounts are designed for, well, basic sites. The hosting service you purchase must match your application requirements. If you need PostgreSQL, Java, Ruby, 1000 mail boxes... and cheapest service from provider XXXX doesn't have it, it isn't because of technical reasons.

Sounds like you're trying to run a SaaS product on a shared hosting account. Completely the wrong tool for the job. Shared hosting is great for a quick, easy and low-budget ready-made environment for simpler sites and applications. Small organisations will value the low cost and ease of setup. But what you appear to be trying to do is likely much more complex - if you're making a database per customer, then presumably you ought to be provisioning them their own runtime environment too for the code, and so on. Consider learning some cloud architecture.

That's assuming you're making a genuine SaaS product where each "user" (that you mentioned) is a separate paying customer who is getting their own self-contained copy of your application. But if they're simply supposed to be users of your small, self-contained web application then it's possible you've just misunderstood the fundamental concepts of relational database design, and should actually just have a single database where all users and data are contained, and you just need to ensure you have columns in the tables to store which user is related to each piece of data.

Whe I just started learning webdev I had some great ideas of solving problems! Which I guess everyone does, in my excitement I got a domain name and web hosting. Life happen still hasn't given up so I use the hosting to test the completed projects while Leaning hence current situation. Regarding the issue the app works as expected on my local envi, and regarding the multiple database the app I want to use as a SaaS was made already ad standalone no tenant ID etc  based on my research more queries and code would be needed to use single db the safety concern, scalability, hence multi db approach

ok well if you want to stick with multi-DB and this general approach then you can't use shared hosting. It's as simple as that really. Maybe just stay with your local environment for testing.

In addition to my previous comment, based on all the information I have read about the pros and cons am biased towards the milti db approach where I just need to make the actual saas laravel app multitenant and use the subdomain with middleware as the seperation point for each tenant. Sorry if the information is all over the place but note the subscription app only handles the subscription and db creation where am having the create db issue,  the actual SaaS app is different. I do know my inexperience is a factor here, hence me seeking help to the issue.

Shared hosts don't let you create databases through code. So while your approach to your SaaS design isn't necessarily invalid, you can't really do it on a shared host accout - it's not designed to host that kind of system. If you wanted to turn this into a serious business proposition you'd have to look at the hosting situation. For now you can just test it locally where you have full control

Thanks to all for the help and  @ADyson, I have decided to split the subscription process in 2 parts registration and tenant creation first with pending status. Then have the db and migration done as a admin function on the back end for testing on the web hosting. Once all my testing is done where all parts working as expected. I will consider my vps options which uses my original automated subscription creation logic. I rather complete the the project rather than worrying about learning vps and config at this point which might be time consuming.  Thanks again!

That's a good idea to split the process. Probably more reliable anyway.

Splitting the process worked where the subscription record is created with a pending status and the tenant record which generate unique db name. The admin for the subscription app checks the pending list use the tenant db name create the db on the back end eg cpanel. Then was able to run the migration from the app  via a button which updates the pending status to active for the subscription record. Took less than I minute to complete the subscription process. Have a seperate controller for the automated process for testing on vps when i get there, but i can proceed to next step. Thanks again!
